# Multiple columns in a single row with CardView Widget

Tags: android

I have implemented two columns in a single row as with using grid view as follows. However I recently came to know there is card view widget, which makes much nicer. But I wonder how it is possible to make two columns in a single row?
If it is possible, do you recommend me to switch from grid view to card view ? Is it commonly used nowadays?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:numColumns="2"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Is the following xml right to make two columns in a single row?

```
<LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use Recyclerview and also cardview. Gridview is an old view and that will be deprecated soon by google. Recyclerview is better than gridview.

You don't have to add two columns in a single row in a Gridview. Instead you can use Recyclerview to get it nice. Cardview is just a list item background of a view. 
-Just design your list item that corredponding to your design
-Add that into RecyclerViewAdaper
-Attach this with RecyclerView
-Get it fixed.

Here is an example for recyclerview with grid item in a card view.

[Recyclerview Grid Item with Cardview](https://github.com/NandagopalR/Recyclerview---Grid---CardView)

Comment: is it possible to provide sample code or any tutorial link?

Comment: sample code for recycler view along with card view inside with two columns in a single row.

Comment: Dude, sorry for my belated source code upload. Just check the code now.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example for using that `RecyclerView` :

https://github.com/javatechig/Android-RecyclerView-Example

Just use `CardView` in this layout:

`List_row.xml`

https://github.com/javatechig/Android-RecyclerView-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/list_row.xml

Something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Textview one"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Textview two"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="36sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And it's not recommended to use that `GridView`.`RecyclerView` already has `GridLayoutManager`.